# nginx rewrite rule, let both rules work not just one of them

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

Im trying to make this redirect work for both rules but have no clue how,
according to the docs this should work and they do separately. but I would like both rules to be applied.

Also the /panel/assets/ folder should be accessible.

Anyone can help me with these rules? Have spend 30+ minutes trying to figure this out.

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
   rewrite ^/panel/(.*) /panel/index.php last;
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert the order as `^/(.*)$` matches also `^/panel/(.*)`. But you certainly could avoid using a if with `try_files` directive. The `break` directive is useless here by the way because the `last` flag performs an internal redirect so it's never reached.

For instance you could turn it to something of this kind :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    rewrite ^/panel/(.*)$ /panel/index.php last;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
}
```

Another idea is to use `map` with `try_files` and do something like this :

```
map $uri $target {
    default          "/404.html";
    "~^/panel/(.*)$" "/panel/index.php";
    "~^/(.*)$"       "/index.php";
}

server {

    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $target;
    }

}
```

It's even better from a performance point of view, but you will have to make sure than the target ressources are available or it will end up in an internal redirection cycle.

Comment: Hello, thank you for posting but both fail. The 1st makes the /panel not work at all anymore

Comment: @user1162685 That's because you have an issue in an other part of your configuration.